# Negative Positioning with JQuery scrollTo / localScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, local, scrollto

I'm working on a project and using Ariel Flesler's jquery.scrollTo.js & jquery.localScroll.js ... I have local links that scroll to various divs on the page.

The trouble I have is that I have a fixed position navbar at the top of the page and ScrollTo is calculating the window position (correctly) without factoring that in.  Below is the scrollTo.js file... can someone show me where and how I would insert code that would cause the Y-axis scroll position to be +[Y]px?

```
/**
 * jQuery.ScrollTo - Easy element scrolling using jQuery.
 * Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Ariel Flesler - aflesler(at)gmail(dot)com | http://flesler.blogspot.com
 * Dual licensed under MIT and GPL.
 * Date: 3/9/2009
 * @author Ariel Flesler
 * @version 1.4.1
 *
 * http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html
 */
;(function($){var m=$.scrollTo=function(b,h,f){$(window).scrollTo(b,h,f)};m.defaults={axis:'xy',duration:parseFloat($.fn.jquery)>=1.3?0:1};m.window=function(b){return $(window).scrollable()};$.fn.scrollable=function(){return this.map(function(){var b=this,h=!b.nodeName||$.inArray(b.nodeName.toLowerCase(),['iframe','#document','html','body'])!=-1;if(!h)return b;var f=(b.contentWindow||b).document||b.ownerDocument||b;return $.browser.safari||f.compatMode=='BackCompat'?f.body:f.documentElement})};$.fn.scrollTo=function(l,j,a){if(typeof j=='object'){a=j;j=0}if(typeof a=='function')a={onAfter:a};if(l=='max')l=9e9;a=$.extend({},m.defaults,a);j=j||a.speed||a.duration;a.queue=a.queue&&a.axis.length>1;if(a.queue)j/=2;a.offset=n(a.offset);a.over=n(a.over);return this.scrollable().each(function(){var k=this,o=$(k),d=l,p,g={},q=o.is('html,body');switch(typeof d){case'number':case'string':if(/^([+-]=)?\d+(\.\d+)?(px)?$/.test(d)){d=n(d);break}d=$(d,this);case'object':if(d.is||d.style)p=(d=$(d)).offset()}$.each(a.axis.split(''),function(b,h){var f=h=='x'?'Left':'Top',i=f.toLowerCase(),c='scroll'+f,r=k[c],s=h=='x'?'Width':'Height';if(p){g[c]=p[i]+(q?0:r-o.offset()[i]);if(a.margin){g[c]-=parseInt(d.css('margin'+f))||0;g[c]-=parseInt(d.css('border'+f+'Width'))||0}g[c]+=a.offset[i]||0;if(a.over[i])g[c]+=d[s.toLowerCase()]()*a.over[i]}else g[c]=d[i];if(/^\d+$/.test(g[c]))g[c]=g[c]<=0?0:Math.min(g[c],u(s));if(!b&&a.queue){if(r!=g[c])t(a.onAfterFirst);delete g[c]}});t(a.onAfter);function t(b){o.animate(g,j,a.easing,b&&function(){b.call(this,l,a)})};function u(b){var h='scroll'+b;if(!q)return k[h];var f='client'+b,i=k.ownerDocument.documentElement,c=k.ownerDocument.body;return Math.max(i[h],c[h])-Math.min(i[f],c[f])}}).end()};function n(b){return typeof b=='object'?b:{top:b,left:b}}})(jQuery);

/**
     * jQuery.LocalScroll - Animated scrolling navigation, using anchors.
     * Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Ariel Flesler - aflesler(at)gmail(dot)com | http://flesler.blogspot.com
     * Dual licensed under MIT and GPL.
     * Date: 3/11/2009
     * @author Ariel Flesler
     * @version 1.2.7
     **/

;(function($){var l=location.href.replace(/#.*/,'');var g=$.localScroll=function(a){$('body').localScroll(a)};g.defaults={duration:1e3,axis:'y',event:'click',stop:true,target:window,reset:true};g.hash=function(a){if(location.hash){a=$.extend({},g.defaults,a);a.hash=false;if(a.reset){var e=a.duration;delete a.duration;$(a.target).scrollTo(0,a);a.duration=e}i(0,location,a)}};$.fn.localScroll=function(b){b=$.extend({},g.defaults,b);return b.lazy?this.bind(b.event,function(a){var e=$([a.target,a.target.parentNode]).filter(d)[0];if(e)i(a,e,b)}):this.find('a,area').filter(d).bind(b.event,function(a){i(a,this,b)}).end().end();function d(){return!!this.href&&!!this.hash&&this.href.replace(this.hash,'')==l&&(!b.filter||$(this).is(b.filter))}};function i(a,e,b){var d=e.hash.slice(1),f=document.getElementById(d)||document.getElementsByName(d)[0];if(!f)return;if(a)a.preventDefault();var h=$(b.target);if(b.lock&&h.is(':animated')||b.onBefore&&b.onBefore.call(b,a,f,h)===false)return;if(b.stop)h.stop(true);if(b.hash){var j=f.id==d?'id':'name',k=$('<a> </a>').attr(j,d).css({position:'absolute',top:$(window).scrollTop(),left:$(window).scrollLeft()});f[j]='';$('body').prepend(k);location=e.hash;k.remove();f[j]=d}h.scrollTo(f,b).trigger('notify.serialScroll',[f])}})(jQuery);
```

Comment: That code is obfuscated. It's kinda difficult to reverse engineer. However, there is probably an option on the plugin that lets you set an initial offset.

Comment: Actually, that code is just minified version of ScrollTo plugin. Their homepage provides a full version as well, just grab and edit it.

Comment: Minified... close enough to obfuscated. ;) Either way, why modify the source when the option is built in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/ . Specifically the offset option.

You can add using the offset with a hash, something like

```
$(...).scrollTo( '#myitem', speed, {offset: {top:20px, left:0} });
```